# Flutter Assets/Images folders plus files show untracked/Contains emphasized items errors

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I had initially run flutter pubs get images an it'd get all images folders/files, but, on adding another image folder/files, The files are no longer getting it assets folder files except the previous ones which are still active.
[image]

I had all the indentation set correctly, which the previous folders/files were gotten correctly, on adding 3 extra images I got these errors:

- Contains emphasized items,
- Untracked.

```
\ uses-material-design: true
 # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
 assets:
   - assets/
   - images/img-icons/
   - images/side-bar/
   - images/dashboard/
   - images/meditation/
```

The images that are giving issues, they all have a .png extensions:

[image]

Note: I had ran flutter pub get more than 10 times!!!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `git` is showing you untracked files?

Comment: And yet, it not working on debug mode

Comment: Have you rebuilt the app? Hot reload / restart doesn't copy new assets.